# run shell script through html button

Tags: php, html

I just started with html and php. I wrote this code to blink a raspberry pi led, but it's not working. I have already changed the permission of all files.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button type="button")"><a href="serverled.php?GO=INT">LED INIT</a></button>
<button type="button")"><a href="serverled.php?GO=ON">LED ON</a></button>
<button type="button")"><a href="serverled.php?GO=OFF">LED OFF</a></button>
</body>
</html>
<?php
session_start();
$action =$_GET['GO'];
switch($action)
{
case "INT":
shell_excec('sudo /bin/bash /var/www/ledinit.sh');
break;

case "ON":
shell_exec('sudo /bin/bash /var/www/ledon.sh');
break;

case "OFF":
shell_exec('sudo /bin/bash /var/www/ledoff.sh');
break;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "now working"? Dump the errors you're getting.

Comment: Can you `sudo` without prompting for password? Also why `session_start()`? Something's wrong with your HTML - what's the brace doing there? `type="button"`

Comment: thanks for your comment,just tell me how to run any php file using html button